# Impala SQL query with 1 table and finding common with 3 hostnames

Tags: sql, impala

I have a single table and am trying to get the destinationhostnames that all users have in common using Impala SQL.

proxy table:

```
sourcehostname destinationhostname
comp1          google.com
comp2          google.com
comp1          yahoo.com
comp1          facebook.com
comp2          facebook.com
comp3          facebook.com
```

When I run the following to get back distinct destinationhostnames from the one table on 2 sourcehostnames this works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.destinationhostname
FROM proxy_table t1 JOIN proxy_table t2
  ON t1.destinationhostname = t2.destinationhostname AND t1.sourcehostname  ="comp1" AND t2.sourcehostname="comp2";
```

It returns:

`google.com` and `facebook.com`

I am trying to return values where `comp1` `comp2` and `comp3` all have something in common which would be `facebook.com` but I cannot get this query quite right:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.destinationhostname
FROM proxy_table t1 JOIN proxy_table t2 JOIN proxy_table t3
  ON t1.destinationhostname = t2.destinationhostname AND t1.sourcehostname  ="comp1" AND t2.sourcehostname="comp2" t3.sourcehostname = "comp3";
```

In the query I would like to specify the distinct 3 computers as there are thousands of them but I only want to select specific ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation.  Assuming no duplicate rows:

```
select destinationhostname
from proxy_table 
group by destinationhostname
having count(*) = (select count(distinct sourcehostname) from proxy_table);
```

If you can have duplicate rows, just change the `having`:

```
having count(distinct sourcehostname) = (select count(distinct sourcehostname) from proxy_table);
```

If you want exactly three users, then just use `= 3`.

Comment: I did not specify but can you change this query so that I can specify the 3 users? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @sectechguy . . . I think you changed the question after I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.destinationhostname
FROM proxy_table t1 JOIN proxy_table t2
ON t1.destinationhostname = t2.destinationhostname 
JOIN proxy_table t3
ON t1.destinationhostname = t3.destinationhostname 
and t2.destinationhostname = t3.destinationhostname 
WHERE
t1.sourcehostname  ="comp1" 
AND t2.sourcehostname="comp2"
AND t3.sourcehostname = "comp3";
```

Let me know, if you face issues

Comment: Did it help out?